# Stacking DataFrame with pd.concat - including column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Stream_Deaths.csv", index_col="Date", parse_dates=["Date"])
df = df.T
df = df.loc["3/11/2020":]
print(df.head())
#Output

Date           Europe  Americas        Asia   Oceania    Africa        US  \#etc
3/11/2020  120.571429  4.000000   69.285714  0.142857  0.285714  3.571429   
3/12/2020  142.000000  4.714286   76.142857  0.142857  0.428571  4.142857   
3/13/2020  188.285714  5.714286   83.571429  0.142857  0.857143  5.000000   
3/14/2020  222.857143  6.857143   93.857143  0.142857  1.000000  5.857143   
3/15/2020  272.285714  8.285714  100.000000  0.000000  1.000000  7.428571
```

I then use `pd.concat` to stack the DataFrame:

```
df_stacked = pd.concat([df["Europe"], df["Americas"], df["Asia"], df["Oceania"], df["Africa"],
            df["US"], df["Brazil"], df["Mexico"], df["UK"], df["Rest of Europe"],
            df["Rest of Latam"],df["India"],df["Rest of Asia"], df["Rest of North America"],
            df["Canada"],df["Bermuda"],df["Greenland"]],
                       axis=0, ignore_index=False)
print(df_stacked.head())
#Output

3/11/2020    120.571429
3/12/2020    142.000000
3/13/2020    188.285714
3/14/2020    222.857143
3/15/2020    272.285714
```

How would I include the column names as an index for the DataFrame? I have tried using the `names` option in `pd.concat` but haven't had any luck so far.
My desired output:

```
Europe    3/11/2020    120.571429
Europe    3/12/2020    142.000000
Europe    3/13/2020    188.285714
Europe    3/14/2020    222.857143
Europe    3/15/2020    272.285714
...
Americas  3/11/2020    120.571429
Americas  3/12/2020    142.000000
Americas  3/13/2020    188.285714
Americas  3/14/2020    222.857143
Americas  3/15/2020    272.285714
#etc
```

Comment: dont concat, instead unstack: `df.set_index('Date').rename_axis('Countries',axis=1).unstack().reset_index(name='yourcol')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, Try:

```
df.melt('Date')
```

Output:

```
         Date  variable       value
0   3/11/2020    Europe  120.571429
1   3/12/2020    Europe  142.000000
2   3/13/2020    Europe  188.285714
3   3/14/2020    Europe  222.857143
4   3/15/2020    Europe  272.285714
5   3/11/2020  Americas    4.000000
6   3/12/2020  Americas    4.714286
7   3/13/2020  Americas    5.714286
8   3/14/2020  Americas    6.857143
9   3/15/2020  Americas    8.285714
10  3/11/2020      Asia   69.285714
11  3/12/2020      Asia   76.142857
12  3/13/2020      Asia   83.571429
13  3/14/2020      Asia   93.857143
14  3/15/2020      Asia  100.000000
15  3/11/2020   Oceania    0.142857
16  3/12/2020   Oceania    0.142857
17  3/13/2020   Oceania    0.142857
18  3/14/2020   Oceania    0.142857
19  3/15/2020   Oceania    0.000000
20  3/11/2020    Africa    0.285714
21  3/12/2020    Africa    0.428571
22  3/13/2020    Africa    0.857143
23  3/14/2020    Africa    1.000000
24  3/15/2020    Africa    1.000000
25  3/11/2020        US    3.571429
26  3/12/2020        US    4.142857
27  3/13/2020        US    5.000000
28  3/14/2020        US    5.857143
29  3/15/2020        US    7.428571
```